# Orchard CMS Custom Form

Tags: orchardcms

I am new to Orchard and still learning.

I created a custom form on Orchard CMS, but when I submit the form as a anonymous, it asks me to login, how do I prevent that as my form is a public form and does not need authentication.

I added a layer to the widget to be not authenticated, but that doesn't seem to work. I've even add a redirect to another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant the custom form permission to the Anonymous role.

http://sebastienros.com/creating-a-contact-form-workflow

Answer (score 2):

To let non logged in people submit a form you need to:

- In the dashboard go to Admin > Users > Roles
- Click 'Anonymous'
- Scroll down to 'Custom Forms' section
- There will be a line called 'Submit {your content type} forms'
- Tick the box next to this
- Scroll down to the bottom and click Save.